# How do I set a timeout to a Geolocation.watchPosition in an Ionic application using capacitor

Tags: google-maps, ionic4, capacitor

I am building an application that tracks users locations and then plot them on the map using Ionic and capacitor. So far it works well but the watch location gets the location approximately every 5 secs. I would like to make the interval longer like 30 - 60 seconds.

I have tried to set options like in the documentation by declaring a "var options" and then passing it as an argument of "watchPosition" but it is not working.Below is the code I am using

```
var options:
{
timeout: 60000
}
  this.isTracking = true;
  this.watch = Geolocation.watchPosition(options, (position, err) => {
    if (position) {
      this.addNewLocation(
        position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude,
        position.timestamp
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a colon after your `var options:` declaration when it should be an equals sign. Also, try to get out of the habit of ever using the `var` keyword over `const` and `let` 
https://hackernoon.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-var-anymore-f109a58b9b70

So, try changing your code to

```
const options = {
   timeout: 60000
};
```